# Get result from GraphTraversal operations with TinkerPop Gremlin and Java

Tags: java, gremlin, amazon-neptune, tinkerpop3

Using TinkerPop Gremlin with Neptune DB, is there a way to get a "result" from a mutation? The `iterate()` returns `GraphTraversal<S, E>`, but is there a way to determine success/fail? Or do we just assume success if there was no exception thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iterate` step has an implicit call to `none`, which returns no results.

If the mutation query has results, perhaps try using `toList` instead. All queries are ACID transactions, so they will either complete (and commit) or fail and throw an exception. So if no exception is thrown, you can assume success, but if you want to see some results, terminating the query with `toList` is probably the best way.